# Data Manipulation of the same data

Tags: html, json, angular, data-manipulation

I have a list of data in a json file. I want display all the months but I want the year that matches to just show as one big year.

Look at the image.
[image: months and year]
The image shows the same data but it's been split into year and month. Rather than it repeating the word 2017 over and over again, I want it just say 2017 in the middle of the pink block. Problem is it needs to correspond with the data as the data changes all the time, where it says 2017 could easily change to 2018 so it needs to say the correct year that the data specifies it is.

JSON:

```
[
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}
{
    "month": "2017-03-01",
    "modelVolume" [{
           "id": 1,
           "model": P213
    }]
}]
```

I'm only using the "month" data for this problem.

HTML:
Year:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col-md-auto">
      <table id="year">
        <tr>
          <th class="y17" class="y18" *ngFor="let value of groupVolumes(groupKeys()[0])" [ngClass]="getYear(value.month)">{{ value.month | date: "yyyy" | uppercase }}</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Month:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
     <div class="col-md-auto" class="scroll">
       <table id ="t2">
          <tr>
            <th class="line">Line 1</th>
            <th class="y18" *ngFor="let value of groupVolumes(groupKeys()[0])" [ngClass]="getYear(value.month)">{{ value.month | date: "MMM" | uppercase }}</th>
          </tr>
```